# How shall I change boot sequenct of a virtual machine in KVM?

Tags: boot, kvm, bios

I have installed Windows 8.1 on a virtual machine in KVM. Now I want to install Windows 10 with the same product key of Windows 8.1, so I try to install Windows 10 on the same virtual machine, overwriting Windows 8.1. So I add a SCSI CDROM device to the virtual machine and with path pointing to the Windows 10 .iso file.

Now when I start the virtual machine, how shall I  enter BIOS to change the boot sequence? I try the following ways, but it always start Windows 8.1:

1. pressing F2 doesn't seem to work, unless I am mistaken of the function keys on the laptop that I am not yet familiar with
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19162267/

   ```
   virsh edit <your-domain-name>
   ```

   doesn't seem to work, because there seems no domain name and I am
   not sure what domain name means (doesn't seem to be the hostname of
   my laptop)

   ```
   $ virsh list
    Id    Name                           State
   ----------------------------------------------------
   $
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a *domain* is a virtual machine

so with this command  **virsh list --all** you must see all virtual machines .

you must be root or at least a privileged account than can talk to libvirtd .

and after you can run

```
virsh edit <your-domain-name>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It works. Now I have a new problem. When I boot into CD DVD to install Windows, it says that it can't find the media driver. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505602/reinstalling-windows-guest-in-kvm-in-lubuntu-host-cant-find-some-media-drivers